# in.android.location.providers_changed: Toggling Location error

Tags: security, gps, geolocation, location-services

Recently in my android smartphone, while toggling GPS the notification popping up "in.android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED".

Why this is happening recently & not before and how to disable it?

Comment: This is caused by some app that uses your location. What apps have you installed recently?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, recently i have not installed any application but certain application received updates from google play. 

I also wants to know that, Is it vulnerable safety wise as this pop up is coming while GPS toggling?

Comment: No, it's probably a debugging message that the app developer left in by accident. It does tell you that that app is finding out when you turn GPS on or off - if you weren't expecting the app to use your location, you should think about revoking its permission.

Comment: Oh ok! Is there a way to find out which application is popping up that message?

Comment: Possibly reposted to [Samsung India Community Forum](https://r2.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S/in-android-location-providers-changed/td-p/2783553).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by uninstalling the NoBroker app.

Comment: According to the response in [Samsung Community Forum](https://r2.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S/in-android-location-providers-changed/m-p/3742923/highlight/true#M289463), this may really help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps that give debug messages for location, as in my case one assistant app. As soon as I uninstalled the app, the messages disappeared.